# Terminal in OSX Lion looks different after unknown command

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion

I spent some time today installing Ruby, Rails and other web development stuff through homebrew and rvm. But somewhere i must have put the wrong command in the terminal since my terminal on OS X Lion (same with both standard terminal and iTerm2) now looks weird.

How do I get rid of that red tilde and black arrow and get it back how it looks as default?

[image: terminal osx lion]

As I am a beginner at terminal commands I would appreciate your help.

Comment: on Terminal window try the command:
"echo $PS1" 
to see what's the value of it.

Comment: That gives me: 
\[\033[0;31m\]\W \[\033[0;30m\] → \[\033[0;37m\]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like PS1 has been changed. 
what you can do now is to change it back, or simply delete it to return to default.

in terminal, do the following:

```
cd ~ 
grep "export PS1" .*
```

then you will see some outputs, it might be in .profile or .bashrc, (just ignore the history one)
you can use whatever to open the file. or just `open .filename` in terminal, delete the line with export PS1, save, relogin. the problem shall be resolved.

Comment: it wasn't in the .profile or .bashrc, I found the PS1 in a file named prompt and the bash_prompt() command. Don't know how the change ended up there. Tried to delete those files and hoped it would return to normal, and it did. Thanks.